# How to construct values println in racket/scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

How to blend the two expressions into one:

```
(map (lambda (x) (println x)) (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))

(map (lambda (x) (println (apply and-l x))) (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))
```

It would be nice to see on the same line the expression before evaluation + '=>' + result of apply. 
For example: `((and-l '(#t #f)) => #f)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `printf` to print and format both values. On a separate note: if you're just *printing* the contents of a list, it's recommended to use `for-each` instead of `map`, we don't need a list as a result. This is what I mean:

```
(for-each (lambda (x)
            (printf "~s => ~s~n" x (apply and-l x)))
          (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))
```